# TeamCity - clean checkout

Tags: unity-game-engine, teamcity

Is it possible to perform "Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build" except of two folders?

I want to mark two folders (which are created during the builds) as "not for cleaning".
To be more specific, I'm using Unity3d to build an app and during the building process, Unity3d creates two folders: Library + Temp.
I would like to keep those folders in order to speedup the next build (Unity3d will use the Library folder as cache).

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

"Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build" is useful when it's required to delete all the files in the checkout directory.

For advanced scenarios, as yours, I suggest using Build Files Cleaner (Swabra) build feature. It can be added from Build Features section. Then configure paths to cleanup as following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, eventually I used the following approach:

- Uncheck "Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build" from the VCS Roots
- Add the following build step as the first step:

  Command line:

  - git add -f Folder1
  - git add -f Folder2
  - git clean -f -d
  - git checkout -- .